# Rollback transaction and No template found for PlayersController#create, rendering head :no_content in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails application, I am creating a has_many associations between Team and players, from console I can save the data but from the browser I am not able to save the data. The values are rolling back and showing `head no content` error in the log.

It is clear that there is a mistake in passing the value from new.html.erb to PlayersContoller. I don't have any validation in player model. I am a beginner, every suggestion is a gem, please help me with valuable guidance

//routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do    
  resources :teams do
    collection do
      get :load_users
    end
  end

  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' } 
  resources :user_roles
  resources :roles
  resources :users 
  resources :players
  root   'home#home'
end
```

// server log

```
Started GET "/players/new?team_id=11" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-28 05:11:28 +0530
Processing by PlayersController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"team_id"=>"11"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/sushmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Team Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/players_controller.rb:4
  Rendering players/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 2], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  ↳ app/views/players/new.html.erb:15
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
  ↳ app/views/players/new.html.erb:34
/home/sushmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/will_paginate-bootstrap-1.0.1/lib/bootstrap_pagination/bootstrap_renderer.rb:11: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
  Rendered players/new.html.erb within layouts/application (71.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 162ms (Views: 118.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)

Started POST "/players" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-28 05:11:31 +0530
Processing by PlayersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kyrK8LmWKA8E8lBsbQTVi2nVdjCvUkbm/tRjk7aLnRy8TlK93E1bBscmVsG//LC5JrxDBdVvyVMybIGTsf2+vQ==", "player"=>{"team_id"=>"11"}, "players"=>{"user_id"=>["1"]}, "commit"=>"Create Player"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/sushmitha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Team Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/players_controller.rb:14
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/players_controller.rb:16
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/players_controller.rb:16
No template found for PlayersController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 79ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

//user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :user_roles, :dependent => :destroy
  # belongs_to :team  ,optional: true, foreign_key: :captain_id    
end
```

//player.rb

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end
```

//team.rb

```
  class Team < ApplicationRecord       
    has_many  :users, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :captain, class_name: 'User'
    has_many  :players, dependent: :destroy

    validates :ground_name, presence:true 
    validates :team_name, presence:true 
    validates :captain_id, presence:true, uniqueness:true
  end
```

//new.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <h3>Add players to team <%= @team.team_name %></h3>
      <%= form_for @player do |f| %>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <%= f.hidden_field :team_id, value: @team.id %>
          <tr>
            <th>Player Id</th>
            <th>Player Name</th>
            <th>Select</th>
          </tr>  
          <% @user.each do |x| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= x.id %></td>
              <td><%= x.full_name %></td>
              <td><%= f.check_box_tag 'players[user_id][]',x.id %></td>
           </tr>
        <% end %>
        <tr>   
          <td>   
            <%= f.submit nil, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
            <%= link_to t('.cancel', default:t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                root_path, class:'btn btn-default' %> 
           </td> 
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table> 
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @user,renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails, previous_label:"old",next_label: "new", inner_window:1, outer_window:1 %>
```

//player controller

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
        def new
            @player= Player.new
            @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
            @user = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page:2)
        end

        def create
            @team = Team.find(params[:player][:team_id])
            params[:player].each do |user_id|
              @team.players.create(user_id: params[:user_id])
            end
        end

private

  def player_params
    params.require(:player).permit(:team_id,:user_id)
  end    
end
```

There is a loop within the form which gives the user_id. How to extract the user info from user model and assign it to form is actually creating confusion for me.

Comment: Please post your `routes.rb` file and your players controller. Also what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Post your errors. Do you have `@team` and `@user` defined in your players controller actions?

Comment: @s3tjan #hashrocket please check it, I have updated my question.

Comment: @gangothri, we need PlayersController code too. And please, explain more clear about players and users. User `has_many :teams` and Team `has_many :users`, they are associated through `players` table, is it correct?

Comment: team has many players, player belongs to user and team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to loop through the symbol and that was the looping error

```
    def create
        @team = Team.find(params[:player][:team_id])
        params[:users].each do |user|
          @team.players.create(user_id: user)
        end
    end
```

made changes in netw.html.erb with following code

```
 <%= check_box_tag 'users[]',x.id %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain how it should be. You have a Player model which helps you to associate users and teams. It means that it should be:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord       
  has_many  :players, dependent: :destroy
  has_many  :users, through: :players
end

class User < ApplicationRecord       
  has_many  :players, dependent: :destroy
  has_many  :teams, through: :players
end
```

You don't need additional `resources :players` line in routes or PlayersController. You just need to update a team to add players. If you want to do it in a separate view, create add_players action in TeamsController. I'll give you a view example for standard new-create/edit-update actions for TeamsController, I suppose you have it already

```
<%= form_for @team do |f| %>
# here goes all other team fields
  <h3>Add players to team <%= @team.team_name %></h3>      
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Player Id</th>
        <th>Player Name</th>
        <th>Select</th>
      </tr>  
      <% User.all.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= user.id %></td>
          <td><%= user.full_name %></td>
          <td><%= check_box_tag 'team[user_ids][]', user.id %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>  
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
  <%= link_to t('.cancel', default:t("helpers.links.cancel")),
            root_path, class:'btn btn-default' %> 
<% end %>
```

Also you should add `user_ids: []` in controller `team_params`

Comment: trainer has asked to retain the use case which has planned, because we already have a team model where we assign the team name groundname and captain id, in the show page of that team, we have to create a link which goes to add players because each player needs team id. use case wants team and players model should be created separately.